# the minicart box is empty and doesnt contain the "You have no items in your shopping cart."

Tags: php, magento, magento2

I installed a magento 2 project and all thing was working. When I click on the minicart and if I didn't add any item, it will show a message: "You have no items in your shopping cart.". I want to rebuild a new header then adding the necessary modules, but when I add the checkout module then I clicked it, I saw that there is not any message, it's only a empty box, why the sentence disappeared ??

Note that I didn't change anything in checkout template, I only added it to my theme.

I don't want to write them it must be exist by default without writing anything in the template

[header image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KxSHh.png)

default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page layout="1column"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="default_head_blocks"/>
    <body>
        <referenceBlock name="authorization-link-login" remove="true" />
        <referenceBlock name="register-link" remove="true" />
        <referenceContainer name="header-wrapper" remove="true" />

        <referenceContainer name="header.container">
            <container name="custom.header" label="navbar" htmlTag="div" htmlClass="navbar">
                <block class="Magento\Theme\Block\Html\Header\Logo" template="Magento_Theme::html/header/logo.phtml" />
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="custom-navbar" template="Magento_Theme::navbar.phtml" />
                <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Search::form.mini.phtml" />
                <!-- <block class="Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar" template="Magento_Checkout::cart/minicart.phtml" /> -->
            </container>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

this is the minicart template

```
<?php
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */

/** @var $block \Magento\Checkout\Block\Cart\Sidebar */
?>

<div data-block="minicart" class="minicart-wrapper">
    <a class="action showcart" href="<?= $block->escapeUrl($block->getShoppingCartUrl()) ?>"
        data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
        <span class="text"><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('My Cart')) ?></span>
        <span class="counter qty empty"
            data-bind="css: { empty: !!getCartParam('summary_count') == false && !isLoading() }, blockLoader: isLoading">
            <span class="counter-number">
                <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
            <span class="counter-label">
                <!-- ko if: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                <!-- ko text: getCartParam('summary_count') -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- ko i18n: 'items' -->
                <!-- /ko -->
                <!-- /ko -->
            </span>
        </span>
    </a>
    <?php if ($block->getIsNeedToDisplaySideBar()) :?>
    <div class="block block-minicart" data-role="dropdownDialog" data-mage-init='{"dropdownDialog":{
                "appendTo":"[data-block=minicart]",
                "triggerTarget":".showcart",
                "timeout": "2000",
                "closeOnMouseLeave": false,
                "closeOnEscape": true,
                "triggerClass":"active",
                "parentClass":"active",
                "buttons":[]}}'>
        <div id="minicart-content-wrapper" data-bind="scope: 'minicart_content'">
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() -->
            <!-- /ko -->
        </div>
        <?= $block->getChildHtml('minicart.addons') ?>
    </div>
    <?php else :?>
    <script>
    require(['jquery'], function($) {
        $('a.action.showcart').click(function() {
            $(document.body).trigger('processStart');
        });
    });
    </script>
    <?php endif ?>
    <script>
    window.checkout = <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getSerializedConfig() ?>;
    </script>
    <script type="text/x-magento-init">
        {
        "[data-block='minicart']": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/core/app": <?= /* @noEscape */ $block->getJsLayout() ?>
        },
        "*": {
            "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader": "<?= $block->escapeJs(
                $block->escapeUrl($block->getViewFileUrl('images/loader-1.gif'))
            ) ?>"
        }
    }
    </script>
</div>
```

Comment: Remove everything from the default.xml and see if that message comes back, clear your cache after the changes